# Adding tab bar to child scenes with own navigation stack using React-Native-Router-Flux in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

We've created a social app to crowdsource opinions. Users have a feed, profile, groups and all that.

We have a bottom tab bar that has buttons for the tabbed scenes mentioned below

**Tabbed scenes**

- Home
- Create post
- Search
- Notifications
- More options

We are using react-native-router-flux for navigation.

---

Current setup

With the current setup, the tab bar is only visible for the Tabbed scenes. When another scene is clicked, they have their own navigation (profile, group, etc.)
Everything works as expected although the tab bar is not visible in other scenes.

---

Expected behaviour

Whenever the user navigates to any scene, the Tab bar and Tab scenes should only mount once. Every other scene (profiles, groups, etc) should have their own navigation stack. They need to be unmounted when the back button is clicked. All scenes should have the tab bar.

Whenever any tab button is clicked, the navigation stack needs to be reset.

App.js is show below

```
<Provider store={store}>
            <RouterWithRedux>

                <Scene hideNavBar key='root'>

                    {/*Login authentication is handled here*/}
                    <Scene initial={true} key="placeholder" component={Placeholder}/>

                    <Scene key="auth">
                        <Scene hideNavBar key="landing" component={LandingPageContainer}/>
                        <Scene key="cookiePolicy" component={CookiePolicy}/>
                        <Scene key="privacyPolicy" component={PrivacyPolicy}/>
                        <Scene key="termsPolicy" component={TermsAndConditions}/>
                    </Scene>

                    <Scene key="traitsSelect" component={TraitsPageContainer} hideNavBar/>

                    <Scene key='main'>
                        <Tabs
                            key="tabbar"
                            showLabel={false}
                            tabBarComponent={BottomNavigation}
                            tabBarPosition="bottom"
                            animationEnabled={false}
                            lazy
                            hideNavBar
                        >

                            <Scene key="home" component={HomePageContainer} navBar={HomePageNavBar}/>
                            <Scene key="search" component={SearchPageContainer} navBar={SearchNavBar}/>
                            <Scene key="moreNavigation" component={MoreNavigationContainer} hideNavBar/>
                            <Scene key="notifications" component={NotificationsContainer}
                                   title="Notifications"/>
                        </Tabs>

                        {/*Need everything below this inside tabs*/}

                        {/*Intro*/}
                        <Scene key="intro" component={Intro} hideNavBar/>

                        {/*Groups*/}
                        <Scene key="myGroups" component={MyGroupsContainer} title='My groups'/>
                        <Scene key="aboutGroup" component={AboutGroupContainer} navBar={MyGroupsNavBar}/>
                        <Scene key="editGroup" path="/editGroup/:userIdParam" component={EditGroupContainer}
                               title='Pending posts in group'/>
                        <Scene key="editGroupMember" path="/editGroupMember/:userIdParam"
                               component={EditGroupMembersContainer} title='Add members'/>
                        <Scene key="createGroup" component={CreateGroupContainer}
                               navBar={CreateGroupNavBar}/>
                        <Scene key="addFriendsToGroup" component={AddFriendsToGroup} hideNavBar/>
                        <Scene key="inviteCode" component={InviteCodeContainer} navBar={InviteCodeNavBar}/>
                        <Scene key="editGroupInfo" path="/editGroupInfo/:userIdParam"
                               component={EditGroupDetailsContainer} navBar={DetailGroupNavBar}/>
                        <Scene key="groupPost" component={PostGroupContainer}/>
                        <Scene key="groupdetail" component={DetailGroupContainer} title='Manage members'/>

                        {/*Profile*/}
                        <Scene key="profile" path="/profile/posts/:userIdParam"
                               component={PostProfileContainer}/>
                        <Scene key="aboutProfile" path="/profile/about/:userIdParam"
                               component={AboutProfileContainer}/>
                        <Scene key="reviewers" path="/profile/reviewers/:userIdParam"
                               component={ReviewersProfileContainer} title="Reviewers"/>

                        {/*Create post*/}
                        <Scene key="createPostSelectType" hideNavBar component={CreatePostSelectType}/>
                        <Scene key="createPost" component={CreatePostContainer} title='Create post'/>
                        <Scene key="createAnonymousPost" component={CreateAnonymousPostContainer}/>

                        {/*Settings*/}
                        <Scene key="settings" component={SettingsContainer}/>
                        <Scene key="changePersonality" component={ChangePersonalityTraitsContainer}
                               hideNavBar/>
                        <Scene key="changePassword" component={ChangePasswordContainer} hideNavBar/>

                        {/*Comments*/}
                        <Scene key="comments" path="/comments/:postIdParam" component={CommentsContainer}
                               title="Comments"/>
                        <Scene key="pendingComments" path="/pending_comments/:userIdParam"
                               component={PendingCommentsContainer} title="Pending comments"/>

                        {/*Posts*/}
                        <Scene key="pendingPosts" component={PostReviewContainer} back
                               title='Awaiting approval'/>
                        <Scene key="singlePost" component={SinglePagePostContainer}/>

                        {/*Points*/}
                        <Scene key="rewards" component={RewardsPageContainer} title='Rewards program'/>
                        <Scene key="referrals" component={ReferralsPageContainer} title='Refer users'/>

                        <Scene key="bannedUsers" component={BannedMembersContainer} title="Banned users"/>
                        <Scene key="ratePersonality" component={RatePersonalityContainer}/>

                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
            </RouterWithRedux>
        </Provider>
```